# How do I prevent a slider from jumping because of a async Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a slider which binds to a property with slow getter and setter. Since the UI needs to be responsive, the binding has the attribute `IsAsync`. But when I drag the slider it jumps between the cursor and 0 (default `FallbackValue`).

Does anybody know how to prevent this behavior, how to disable the `FallbackValue`?

XAML:

```
<Slider>
  <Slider.Value>
    <Binding Path="Value" IsAsync="True"/>
    <!-- For testing, best plan till now
    <PriorityBinding>
      <Binding Path="Value" IsAsync="True"/>
      <Binding Path="CurrentValue"/>
    </PriorityBinding>
    -->
  </Slider.Value>
</Slider>
```

Code Behind:

```
public int Value
{
  get
  {
    //if (setterCount > 0)    // For testing, best plan till now
    //{
    //  return CurrentValue;
    //}
    Thread.Sleep(100);        // Just for simulating slow functionality
    return myValue;
  }
  set
  {
    //++setterCount;          // For testing, best plan till now
    //CurrentValue = value;
    Thread.Sleep(200);        // Just for simulating slow functionality
    myValue = value;
    //--setterCount;
    OnPropertyChanged("Value");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in the tags

Comment: Simple: Don't put blocking operations in properties. Use interactivity trigger to call a command when the slider changes it#s values

Comment: @Tseng Not helpful. It doesn't block! Therefor the [`IsAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync.aspx) attribute is there. I simply have just the Property.

Comment: @Andy: Its not blocking the UI thread, but the vm itself. Since it doesn't fire the OnPropertyChanged value, the UI is not getting notifed about the new value and falls back. Just set the value and correct/validate it later via command (or pass the current value via command and validate it there, then set it if successful

Comment: Properties in a ViewModel should *not* be doing anything so heavy that it causes delays. That's the whole point of the MVVM pattern. Any work that needs to be done to calculate the value should be done before setting the property value, or, as a last resort, in the setter

Answer (score 2):

Just don't call blocking operations inside a property, they aren't meant for this.

Bind the value normally and query/validate it's input inside a command.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="ValueChanged">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding UpdateSomethingCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And do the async in your command

```
public ICommand UpdateSomethingCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(UpdateSomething);
private async void UpdateSomething() 
{
    await SomeLengthlyCallOrValidation(this.SliderValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solution can be considered "pure MVVM" but let's propose it and see if it fits you.
First of all, we define a Slider and subscribe to the Thumb.DragCompleted event. We also set UpdateSourceTrigger to explicit:

```
<Slider Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Width="300" x:Name="slid" Thumb.DragCompleted="MySlider_DragCompleted" >
        <Slider.Value>
            <Binding Path="Value" UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit"/>
        </Slider.Value>
</Slider>
```

Now in the event handler in codebehind we do this:

```
private void MySlider_DragCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{     
    BindingExpression be = slid.GetBindingExpression(Slider.ValueProperty);
    be.UpdateSource();
}
```

Summing up, what we are doing here is just doing the binding (getting/setting the slider value) only when the "sliding" process is completed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make getter asynchronous, simply store (cache) last value.
You can bind to a property normally and implement asynchronous update yourself:

view:

```
<Slider Value="{Binding Value, Delay=100}" Maximum="..." />
```

viewmodel:

```
Task _task = Task.Run(() => { }); // Task.CompletedTask in 4.6
volatile int _id;

double _value;
public double Value
{
    get { return _value; }
    set
    {
        _value = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        // task
        var id = ++_id; // capture id
        _task = _task.ContinueWith(o =>
        {
            if (_id == id)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // simulate work
                // this is optional if value stays the same
                if (_id == id)
                {
                    _value = value + 10; // simulate different value
                    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value)));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The idea: *record* slider value changes and execute only last one.

Recording is done by chaining tasks with `ContinueWith`. At first you have completed task, every change of `Value` will create a new task.

I don't know if there is a way to check whenever current task has continuation, therefore `_id` is used for this. When `_id == id` task is the last in the chain (otherwise task do nothing, as there are more actual updates).

Second `if` is used to check whenever **after** work there are more tasks and prevent value to change *back* (effect you have currently). This notification is needed if your work can return different value than the one what was set. Otherwise remove second `if` completely (it's not needed).

Notice `Delay` in binding, it will reduce number of tasks (without it one movement of slider may produce dozens of task).

Comment: It's still blocking, you're calling `.Result`. And you can't use `await` there

Comment: When you call `Task...Result` it blocks the setter, because it waits for the Task to finish.

Comment: You are right, didn't noticed behavior with `100 ms`. Let me rethink it.